# Java - Spring Boot project used with many contextpaths

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, war, dependency-management

I have a Spring Boot Project called SuperProject and I want to use this project with differents contexts paths.
For example: paths 'baseUrl/client1', and 'baseUrl/client2', and 'baseUrl/clientX' will use the same logic and use cases defined on SuperProject.

All of this clients will use different database url connections, but the tables will be equals, so the client project will work.

So basically I should to only change the .properties/.yml file for each client.
However I can't have repeated code, because if I have to change any logic/use case, all of this clients will need to change too.

I think that i have to develop a .war library and share it by maven into all "client projects". But I don't know if the webservices url's, defined on SuperProject, will be mapped when i compile the projects.

How can I do that? Is this idea the best approach?

Comment: Just put the configuration in `application.properties` set the `server.context-path` property to the general part and `server.servlet-path` to your client speficic path. No need to do anything else imho...

Comment: Are you saying that should I have to create different modules and add all of general configurations into the parent module properties and the specific configurations into the clients modules properties?

Comment: Why would you need multiple projects? Just create a single one, and for a client prepare a specific `application.properties` file.

Comment: Because a client could change one or more use cases. So for this clients the project will be equal except these use cases. I think that multiprojects using the same source (by maven or jar or a parent module) is a good approach. Do you have another solution?

Comment: Then create a shared jar, add the globally unique configuration, and then for your clients create separate projects, containing the client specific configuration.

Comment: Nice! I'm trying this now but I have any doubts. For example, if I define my controllers in jar project, these controllers will be mapped in the client project? And could I define global configurations (using .properties file) into jar file and use this configurations on client project?

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can use "assembly" plugin for maven with different environments. Eventually, maven will create packages for each client.